# wordpress - registering, enqueuing, and adding javascript functions.php

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I know that there are several posts on this here, but having gone through a ton of them, I am still having problems. So - up front apologies on adding *another* question on something that seems so straightforward but I'm new to this and stuck!

That being said - I have soundclick.js. It lives in my theme's js folder. It works pasted straight into the header - but i need it in my functions.php file like all the other good little javascripts.

```
function wpana_js() {

  wp_register_script('soundclick', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/soundclick.js', array(), '0', false);
  wp_enqueue_script('soundclick');
} 

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpana_js');
```

Code goes in - javascript shows up in the page source, but then my calls to the javascript to get these sounds to play on a user click don't work anymore. (the calls worked just dandy when the javascript was pasted directly into the header)

Am i missing something obvious on getting the javascript back into working status? Thanks!

***update*** i fixed the problem - apparently i was queuing correctly, but my problem lay in the js file itself. there was a basic problem with how i made the file. so it was showing up but not working. thanks all for taking a look :)

Comment: So let me see if I am understanding this correctly, the javascript is loading into the browser, but it is not working the script itself?

Answer (score 2):

I would inspect the *order* in which your scripts are being loaded when

- it works by pasting it directly into the header, versus
- it's loaded via `wp_enqueue_script()` as you've done in `functions.php`

Is this library getting loaded *after* your JavaScript code that attempts to use it?  Is soundclick.js a jQuery plugin?

If you need to load some scripts after others, ensure you define the dependent scripts in the array parameter like so (for example, if this script requires jQuery)

```
wp_register_script('soundclick', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/soundclick.js', array('jquery'), '0', false);
```

Comment: I was suspecting this as well but was trying to make sure the script was loading into the browser first.